# While loop with true, if and break

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, break

How do i change these two While loops into other two while loops (the output should be the same)
using "while (true) { ... })" and using "if" and "break"  inside the loop to  terminate it?

The output

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
42 36 30 24 18 12 6
```

```
int m = 0;

while (m <= 7) {
    System.out.print(m + " ");
    m++;
}

System.out.println();
int MM = 42;
while (MM >= 6) {
    System.out.print(MM + " ");
    MM -= 6;
}

System.out.println();
```

Comment: move the logic that exits your loop `m <= 7` for example, into an if statement at the end of your loop

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int m = 0;

while (true){
    System.out.print(m + " ");
    m++;
    if(m > 7){
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println();
int MM = 42;
while (true) {
    System.out.print(MM + " ");
    MM -= 6;
    if(MM < 6){
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println();
```

Comment: Or `if( !(m <= 7)){ break; }`.  Either works.  Ditto for the other `if`.

Comment: segev_gr , i tried so many times to recreate the loops and probably came up with something similar, but it never worked so i guess my math was off, thanks man! thanks everyone

Comment: but why when i combine these 4 loops together in order the output is ?
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 next line 
42 36 30 24 18 12 6 next line 
8  next line
0